# Redirect Facebook App to Facebook Canvas App (Fluid width)

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I'm having a mental meltdown with Facebook and the way it handles Apps and Canvas Apps (apps with fluid width).

I can't figure out how to get a Page Tab to link to a fluid app. You can see an example on Coca Cola's fan page.

https://www.facebook.com/cocacola > Coce Zone tab

First it loads normal blank app which reloads to fluid app.

I have looked at the redirect code and it seems to be a form that submits itself after the page is done loading. After a bit of research I figured out that Facebook creates that itself.

My Page App directs to [here](http://apps.facebook.com/ford-koeajotalkoot) but console says this:

```
Refused to display 'https://apps.facebook.com/ford-koeajotalkoot/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Comment: You have to redirect in the top window instance - and that means you have to use JavaScript, `top.location.href="https://apps.facebook.com/ford-koeajotalkoot/";`

Comment: But I'm not doing the redirect by hand. Facebook is doing it by itself.

Comment: No, Facebook does not automatically redirect from page tab to canvas.

Comment: I can't believe I actually got it to work. I fought with that so many hours and finally it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app settings below the **Page Tab** there's **Page Tab URL**. There you must put an url to file with the redirect. It can be as simple file as below:

```
<script>
top.location.href="https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_CANVAS_URL/";
</script>
```

It will then redirect to your app.